# How to insert image from sqlite to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-imageview

Here is my Database Helper activity:

```
public List<Product> getListProduct() {
    Product product = null;
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Product", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2), cursor.getString(3));
        productList.add(product);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return productList;
}
```

---

I am using sqlite as my database and i want it to appear in my listview right beside the name of the item. any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Full-size pictures are too large to stick inside a SQLite database, much less an Intent. They will need a place to live on your device’s file system.
Normally, you would put them in your private storage. Recall that you used your private storage to save your SQLite database. With methods like

```
Context.getFileStreamPath(String)
```

and

```
Context.getFilesDir()
```

You can do the same thing with regular files, too (which will live in a
subfolder adjacent to the databasessubfolder your SQLite database lives in).